# nav2-smac-planner package not available on foxy

Tags: nav2, ros-foxy

I'm trying to install the nav2-smac-planner package on Foxy but apt install can't find it. Is it not available?

Here seem to indicate it's available on Foxy both source and debian.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted the same question on github and Steve Macenski replied:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3549

> Its called just the Smac Planner in Foxy https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/foxy-devel/smac_planner mostly due to me messing the naming up. I couldn't change the name back after release so we just have to live with it like that in Foxy unfortunately. I would definitely recommend upgrading to at least Galactic though if you're using the Smac Planner. There are many updates made that were not backported to Foxy.

Comment: This is the correct answer, if this could be accepted